# Finding shortest path which have to pass through set of predefined nodes

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, path-finding

I need help finding the shortest path between two nodes in an weighted directed graph which have to pass through set of predefined nodes.

I made small research and I came to a conclusion that this problem can be solved  just find all posible paths between A/Z nodes, but it imposible for my case by performance (graph is big 50 000 nodes and 500 000 edges)

Any idea of the algorithm I could use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please tell if order of predefined nodes is fixed?

Comment: Yes. Order of predefined nodes is fixed.